# add variable to innerHTML element

Tags: javascript, html

How can I change the text in the labels (in the innerHTML element) below to a variable value according to the counterID assigned to eventDiv element?

```
function addRow() {
var eventDiv = document.createElement('div');

var counterID = counterID + 1;

eventDiv.setAttribute('id', counterID);

eventDiv.className = 'event_cont';

eventDiv.innerHTML =

'<div class="cont" onclick="addRow()">\
  <div class="dep_cont">\
    <div class="cont_label">\
     <label id="dep_cont_label">Departure</label>\
   </div>\
   <div class="cont_time">\
     <label>10:00 AM</label>\
   </div>\
   <div class="cont_icon">\
     <img src="icons/geo_loc.png" width="30px" height="30px" alt="" title=""/>\
   </div>\
 </div>\
 <div class="des_cont">\
   <div class="cont_label">\
     <label>Destination</label>\
   </div>\
   <div class="cont_time">\
     <label>10:00 AM</label>\
   </div>\
   <div class="cont_icon">\
     <img src="icons/end_RH.png" width="30px" height="30px" alt="" title=""/>\
   </div>\
 </div>\
</div>';

document.getElementById('tab_cont').appendChild(eventDiv);

document.getElementById('dep_cont_label').innerHTML = document.getElementById('dep_loc_input').value;
```

}

The result for the above is only changing the text of the label for the first element created dynamically

Comment: `counterId` needs to be declared globally and remove `var` from within this method.

Comment: ^-- + use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) instead of a string.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using the same id for every eventDiv you have created.

First of all, you should define CounterID outside the function. Moreover, every time you use this function to create a div and append it to the 'tab_cont', you are using same id's 'dep_cont_label','dep_loc_input'. Id attribute should be unique.

Comment: how can I implement the variable counterID in the element ?

Comment: you should declare it outside function.
var counterID = 0;
function addRow(){
counterID++
}